# How to fetch core data objects into Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, core-data

I've saved objects in core data, and I am looking how to fetch those objects as a Dictionary

Here is an example of my code where sections is keys for the dictionary and Company as an array of core data objects.

```
private var companies = Dictionary<String, Array<Company>>()
private var sections: [String] = ["Pending", "Active", "Pending"]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Company> = Company.fetchRequest()
            let moc = DatabaseController.getContext()
            do {
                let request = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
                for case let (index, object) in request.enumerated() {
                   companies[sections[index]]!.append(object)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }}
```

When I am trying to execute my code, I have an error:

[image]

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Could anyone help me with that issue?

Comment: Fetched objects are returned always as an **array**, either as `[NSManagedObject]` or `[[String:Any]]` depending on the fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that you're force unwrapping an optional that doesn't have a value. In other words you're using `!` where you shouldn't. (You should basically never use the force unwrap operator (`!`).)

Let's look at the line where you do that:

```
companies[sections[index]]!.append(object)
```

If we break this down and add the inferred types we have:

```
let section: String? = sections[index]
let companyArray: Array<Company> = companies[section]!
```

You're crashing because `companies` starts off empty, so asking for any of the arrays will return `nil`. (Actually, I'm not sure how your code is compiling, since you can't subscript into the dictionary with an optional.)

However, if you fix that, we still have a problem because you're using the index of the fetched array to look up the section. If you have more than three companies, that will start to fail.

I suspect you want something like:

```
for let company in result {
    if var companyArray = companies[company.status] {
        companyArray.append(company)
    } else {
        companies[company.status] = [company]
    }
}
```

Where `status` is an invented property on `Company` that returns a `String` like "Pending" or "Active".

Comment: I've tried to use your code and I have another issue now. So, I can only save 1 company for each section ("Active" and "Pending"). Is it possible to have multiple companies for the section? My main purpose to create a dictionary is to fill the tableView with sections. @dave

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, just need to use NSFetchResultController in order to display data in TableView by different sections.